# Can't binding to Textblock in mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Using the MVVM pattern, the UI of the application and the underlying presentation and business logic .XAML and code:
textblocks,images defined like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:TweetVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image x:Name="Thumbnail" Source="{Binding GetAccount.ProfileImgUrl}" Width="100" Margin="8"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="8">
                <TextBlock x:Name="UserName" Text="{Binding GetAccount.Name}" Foreground="#262626" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AccountName" Text="{Binding GetAccount.ScreenName}" Foreground="#666666"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
```

CODE: 
Here is full code:

```
public class TweetVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Accounts getAccount;
    public Accounts GetAccount {
        get { return getAccount; }
        set
        {
            getAccount = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GetAccount"));
        }
    }
  public TweetVM()
    {

       GetProfile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public async void GetProfile()
    {
        try
        {
            GetAccount = new Accounts();
            var profile = await(from index in twtContext.Account
                                where index.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials
                                select index).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            GetAccount.Name = profile.User.Name;
            GetAccount.ProfileImgUrl = profile.User.ProfileImageUrl;
            GetAccount.ScreenName = profile.User.ScreenNameResponse;             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorDialog = new ErrorDialog(ex.Message, "Error : ");
        }
    }
```

GetAccount has got data but don't see binding to textblock,... What's problem?.
I don't understand where the problem?...

Comment: Check `BindingMode`

Comment: Your problem is `async void` method. Because method didn't return `Task` you cannot observe result. If `GetProfile` method will throw exception - nothing happenned -what is obviously heppenned in your case

Comment: No errors.var profile = await(from index in twtContext.Account....

Comment: I try to replace void into Task
public async Task GetProfile()

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If yes, then where ? If in the `ViewModel`, then you need `public GetAccounts { get {return _getAccount;} set {_getAccount = value; OnPropertyChanged("GetAccounts");}}`

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Accounts getAccount;
        public Accounts GetAccount {
            get { return getAccount; }
            set
            {
                getAccount = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GetAccount"));
            }
        }

Comment: don't see anything

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the following: Constructor of View, Implementation of Accounts class, and the method you provided in comment ?

Comment: simply take Snoop and check your DataContext and Binding at runtime - its always one of the two

Comment: Update my code...

Comment: Thanh the way you have implemented it you need the IPropertyChanged in your Accounts class as well. That's why I wanted to see the constructor of View class and implementation of Accounts class

Comment: I don't write behind code. So <Page.DataContext> <ViewModel:TweetVM/> </Page.DataContext> on XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comments then if you do this it should work:

```
var profile = await(from index in twtContext.Account
  where index.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials
    select index).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

GetAccount = new Accounts()
{
   Name = profile.User.Name,
   ProfileImgUrl = profile.User.ProfileImageUrl,
   ScreenName = profile.User.ScreenNameResponse
}
```

Comment: Yes, successfully.

Comment: be careful - if this solution works - and this would work too if Accounts did NOT implement INotifyPropertyChanged - you should really check your Accounts class - or better post it here ;)

Comment: This solution works because he didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Accounts class. If he did, then his own solution would have worked

Comment: i know but i dont know if he knows it ;) But if he did not want to alter the values - he should change the Binding Mode to OneTime too

Comment: @blindmeis, you are right. But I guess I mentioned it a couple of times in the comments, same did you. He will eventually learn it one day. And I guess that one day is not today.

Answer (score 0):

use Snoop and check the following:

- DataContext of the view should be an instance of TweetVM
- Accounts class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
- Accounts Properties(you bind to) have to be public

if all these 3 points are valid it should work.

Comment: That is simple as
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:TweetVM/>
</Page.DataContext>

Comment: i never use this style of setting the DataContext in MVVM projects :) thats why i fail to see it.

Comment: That is the legit way if doing it

Comment: i use datatemplates for setting the datacontext to my views or do it in codebehind for my "MainView".

Comment: Also a legit way, but doing it this way you will see all bindings in the editor, and also if you have typed them wrong or if there is any mistake.

Comment: if you use DI or have constructors with parameters it beginning to be hard this xaml way ;)

Comment: Absolutely right. just wanted to point that this is a legit way of doing it. probably more correct than all the other ways.

Comment: i never said its worng :) just not the way i do it. but thx for pointing it out.